# Google Apps Script Cannot find method createFile((class))

Tags: file-upload, google-apps-script

I just started scripting my first Google App and i can't seem to get pass this error.
What my script does is that it creates a form that allows users to enter data into a google spreadsheet.
And upload a file into the folder BIO.
Please help me out!
This is the code.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('New app');
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AvOeZM3IzF-GdDRyV3NiTjBreC1ONXh0cHdDMlFhRGc');
  var grid = app.createGrid(5, 2);
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Code:'));
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('codeName'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Uploaded Date'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('date'));
  grid.setWidget(2, 0, app.createLabel("maid's Name"));
  grid.setWidget(2, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('maidName'));

//creates vertical panel and declare as panel
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.add(grid);


  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
   panel.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
  form.add(panel);

//creates submit button and declare as button
  var button = app.createButton('submit');

//notsure
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('b');

//notsure
  handler.addCallbackElement(grid);

//notsure
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

//add submit button to panel.
  panel.add(button);

//addpanel to application
  app.add(panel);

//display application


  app.add(form);

  return app;
}

function b(e) {

 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AvOeZM3IzF-GdDRyV3NiTjBreC1ONXh0cHdDMlFhRGc');
 var lastRow = doc.getLastRow(); //Find the last row
 var cell = doc.getRange('a1').offset(lastRow, 0); //finds the next empty cell in column A

cell.setValue(e.parameter.codeName);//i can access paremeter codeName because i setname('codeName') just now.
cell.offset(0, 1).setValue(e.parameter.date);
cell.offset(0, 2).setValue(e.parameter.maidName);

  var Blob = e.parameter.thefile;
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('BIO');
  folder.createFile(Blob);



var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); 
  var label = app.createLabel('File Upload Sucess')
  app.close(); //close widget
  return app; //close widget


}
```

Thank you guys in advance!
Jasper.

Comment: Class UiApp was deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to upload a file in a form you have to use a doGet() / doPost() structure and use a submitButton instead of the 'normal' button you are using.

Note that this configuration does not require to add a callBackElement.

Note also that the form must contain only one element and that the fileUpload widget must be a child of the form. I changed a bit the organization of your Ui creation to make it (hopefully) more clear.

You code should be as follows  (didn't check for typos) :

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('New app');
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AnqSFd3iikE3dFBub2t1Ry1PaXJUMUVkSVVSempCenc');
  var form = app.createFormPanel();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var grid = app.createGrid(5, 2);
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Code:'));
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('codeName'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Uploaded Date'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('date'));
  grid.setWidget(2, 0, app.createLabel("maid's Name"));
  grid.setWidget(2, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('maidName'));
  //creates vertical panel and declare as panel
  panel.add(grid);
  panel.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
  form.add(panel);
  app.add(form);
  var button = app.createSubmitButton('submit');
  panel.add(button);
  return app;
}



function doPost(e) {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AvOeZM3IzF-GdDRyV3NiTjBreC1ONXh0cHdDMlFhRGc');
  var lastRow = doc.getLastRow(); //Find the last row
  var cell = doc.getRange('a1').offset(lastRow, 0); //finds the next empty cell in column A
  cell.setValue(e.parameter.codeName);//i can access paremeter codeName because i setname('codeName') just now.
  cell.offset(0, 1).setValue(e.parameter.date);
  cell.offset(0, 2).setValue(e.parameter.maidName);
  var Blob = e.parameter.thefile;
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('BIO');
  folder.createFile(Blob);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); 
  var label = app.createLabel('File Upload Success')
  app.add(label);
  return app; //close widget
}
```

---

EDIT following your comment :

to get the url of the file you just uploaded, change the code like this :

```
  ...
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('BIO');
  var url = folder.createFile(Blob).getUrl();
  Logger.log(url);
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
It works like a charm!
So the problem on my side was the dopost!
I have some questions.
How come its dopost(e)? And not dopost(f) or dopost(c)?
And i was toying around with the code but i can't seem to find a way to return the url string of the uploaded file.
I am trying to upload the file, obtain the url and paste it on myspreadsheet. But i can't seem to find a way to obtain the url. Google Gurus! Help me out please!
And thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for accepting. e comes for enent info, you can use another letter of your choice but the you'll have to change in code every occurrence of it... e.parameter.thefile would become c.parameter.thefile if you use c as letter...  - To get the url see edit.

Comment: Oops... typo : should read "e comes for eVent info..." of course :)