# Cannot find method createFile ((class)) in Folder class

Tags: google-apps-script

I made a simple file uploader a while back, and now it stopped working for some reason. When I click **Upload File**, it returns this error:

```
InternalError: Cannot find method createFile((class)).
```

Here's Code.gs:

```js
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen() {
  // Add a menu with some items, some separators, and a sub-menu.
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('RC Publications')
      .addItem('Upload File', 'upload')
      .addToUi();
}

function upload() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(
      HtmlService
          .createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html')
          .setTitle('Upload File')
          .setWidth(350 /* pixels */));
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    var folderId = "insert-drive-id-here";
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

    var blob = form.myFile;
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);

    return "File uploaded successfully. Use the following code in the form:<p /><p /> " + file.getId();

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

Here's form.html:

```html
<div>
<form id="myForm">
Use the following form to upload an image file for the RC Publications App.
    <input type="file" name="myFile" id="fileUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
           onclick="this.value='Uploading...';
                    document.getElementById('fileUpload').disabled=true;
                    this.disabled=true;
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;">
</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }
</script>

<style>
 input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>

</div>
```

I've seen someone else with a similar problem, [Google Apps Script Cannot find method createFile((class))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679901/google-apps-script-cannot-find-method-createfileclass), but their question uses the deprecated UiService classes, so is not directly applicable here. My code worked fine before and for some reason stopped working now... Any idea why this is occurring, or how to fix it?

The strange thing is, when I add the following line to uploadFiles(), the error turns into "undefined" instead:

```
DocumentApp.getUi().alert("hi");
```

I think the last one is a weird bug...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679901/google-apps-script-cannot-find-method-createfileclass

Comment: @d.datul1990 - The OP referred to that question, and explained why it's not a duplicate.